# Getting latest record for each userid in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have user with name, location, created_at as important fields in table.
I want to retrieve for each user the latest location,i.e, I want something like this:

```
username    location       created_at
abc         New York       2012-08-18 16:18:57
xyz         Mexico city    2012-08-18 16:18:57
abc         Atlanta        2012-08-11 16:18:57
```

only input is UId(1,2) array of userids.please help me to accomplish this.I just want to know how to write query using active record query interface.

Comment: By 'latest' I mean largest created_at value

Comment: What dbms are you using? And what is your goal, getting the data or avoiding any SQL in your model code?

Comment: I am using mysql and want it independent of database

Comment: Also, the table may have pretty basic normalization problems. You may want to move locations out of `users`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, this should be a standard way to solve this kind of problems:

```
SELECT l1.user, l1.location
FROM locations l1
LEFT JOIN locations l2 ON l1.user = l2.user AND l2.created_at > l1.created_at
WHERE l2.id IS NULL
```

The idea is to join the table with itself, and find those rows which don't have any row with the same `user` and **greater** `created_at`.

Of course, you should have `(user, created_at)` index on your table.

Now you should see how would that be represented in AR interface.

Comment: Just curious what is the purpose of the `WHERE l2.id IS NULL`?

Comment: Without it you will have a bunch of records where `l2.created_at` is indeed greater than `l1.created_at`. This way, we leave here just the records with maximum `l1.created_at` (for the user).

Answer (score 0):

When

```
u_id
```

is the array of user ids, then

```
u_id.map{|i| User.find(i).location}
```

should be an array of the users locations.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use

```
User.where(:uid => [1,2,3]).maximum('location')
```

which will create something like

```
SELECT MAX(`users`.`location`) AS max_id FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IN (1, 2,3)
```